# how to ensure Spring batch job completion when using async call in writer step

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-batch

My spring batch process reads millions of rows from a DB in a read step,
and publishing it to a kafka topic in the write step.

In the corporate I'm working we are using a wrapper on kafka and I'm currently calling a sendAsync() method which takes in eventSupplier the message and a callback: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback

My question is since it is a batch I'm afraid that the job execution will end before I get indication on all the messages sent in async mode. ( perhaps exceptions were thrown on the last msgs)

Is there a spring batch platform supported way to ensure step completion ?
or should I just implement Future.isDone() in the write step ?
I saw in the spring batch documentation that there is a KafkaItemWriter should I use it in my case ? I'm currently implementing ItemWriter
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [KafkaItemWriter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemWriter.java) provided by Spring Batch waits for the async call to return (up to a configurable timeout). This is to ensure that the write operation has succeeded or failed.

If you are writing a custom `ItemWriter`, you can get inspiration from that.